# What does the refresh button/option do exactly?

Tags: windows

We do refresh the window in many occasions.  Whenever system is slow we refresh, when we copy or move something we refresh, when we delete we refresh... etc..

What does the refresh button/option do exactly in windows? Might look a silly question, but I eagrly want to know about it..

Answer (score 0):

It can do whatever the programmer wants it to do. Usually that is redrawing some parts of the GUI. Sometimes that infers the need of recalculating something. Sometimes that infers the need of retrieving some data again, possibly from a file or the network.

ps. Isn't everything a file in the end?